# TPU throws error when trying to initiliase and setup, and then later during tf.keras model building

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I ran this block of code using *TF 2.2.0, Keras and some TPU* config:

```
try:
    TPU_WORKER = os.environ["TPU_NAME"]
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
    print(f"Running on TPU: {tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict()['worker']}")
    print(f"TPU_WORKER: {TPU_WORKER}")
except ValueError: 
    tpu = None
    gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices("GPU")

if tpu:
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
    strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
elif len(gpus) > 1: # multiple GPUs on the VM
    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(gpus)
else:
    strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()
```

and got this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-a49335a43189> in <module>
     15 
     16 if tpu:
---> 17     tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
     18     tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
     19     strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/remote.py in connect_to_cluster(cluster_spec_or_resolver, job_name, task_index, protocol, make_master_device_default, cluster_device_filters)
    181     context.set_server_def(server_def)
    182   else:
--> 183     context.update_server_def(server_def)
    184 
    185   if make_master_device_default and isinstance(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py in update_server_def(server_def)
   2137 
   2138 def update_server_def(server_def):
-> 2139   context().update_server_def(server_def)
   2140 
   2141 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py in update_server_def(self, server_def, keep_alive_secs)
    596       # Current executor might have pending nodes that involves updated remote
    597       # devices. Wait for them to finish before updating.
--> 598       self.executor.wait()
    599       self.executor.clear_error()
    600       pywrap_tfe.TFE_ContextUpdateServerDef(self._context_handle,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/executor.py in wait(self)
     65   def wait(self):
     66     """Waits for ops dispatched in this executor to finish."""
---> 67     pywrap_tfe.TFE_ExecutorWaitForAllPendingNodes(self._handle)
     68 
     69   def clear_error(self):

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __inference_train_function_75067}} Compilation failure: XLA can't deduce compile time constant output shape for strided slice: [4,?], output shape must be a compile-time constant
     [[{{node model/tf_op_layer_strided_slice/strided_slice}}]]
    TPU compilation failed
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_6359544293025479410/_3]]
```

This error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __inference_train_function_75067}} Compilation failure: XLA can't deduce compile time constant output shape for strided slice: [4,?], output shape must be a compile-time constant
     [[{{node model/tf_op_layer_strided_slice/strided_slice}}]]
    TPU compilation failed
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_6359544293025479410/_3]]
```

did occur during the previous run and now since then, I can't re-run my code.

The workaround would be to restart the notebook instead and re-run it.

But then I get the same error elsewhere:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    853                 context.async_wait()
    854               logs = tmp_logs  # No error, now safe to assign to logs.
--> 855               callbacks.on_train_batch_end(step, logs)
    856         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
    857 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
    387     """
    388     if self._should_call_train_batch_hooks:
--> 389       logs = self._process_logs(logs)
    390       self._call_batch_hook(ModeKeys.TRAIN, 'end', batch, logs=logs)
    391 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _process_logs(self, logs)
    263     """Turns tensors into numpy arrays or Python scalars."""
    264     if logs:
--> 265       return tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
    266     return {}
    267 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py in to_numpy_or_python_type(tensors)
    521     return t  # Don't turn ragged or sparse tensors to NumPy.
    522 
--> 523   return nest.map_structure(_to_single_numpy_or_python_type, tensors)
    524 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    615 
    616   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 617       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    618       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    619 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    615 
    616   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 617       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    618       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    619 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py in _to_single_numpy_or_python_type(t)
    517   def _to_single_numpy_or_python_type(t):
    518     if isinstance(t, ops.Tensor):
--> 519       x = t.numpy()
    520       return x.item() if np.ndim(x) == 0 else x
    521     return t  # Don't turn ragged or sparse tensors to NumPy.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in numpy(self)
    959     """
    960     # TODO(slebedev): Consider avoiding a copy for non-CPU or remote tensors.
--> 961     maybe_arr = self._numpy()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    962     return maybe_arr.copy() if isinstance(maybe_arr, np.ndarray) else maybe_arr
    963 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _numpy(self)
    927       return self._numpy_internal()
    928     except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
--> 929       six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)
    930 
    931   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __inference_train_function_78422}} Compilation failure: XLA can't deduce compile time constant output shape for strided slice: [16,?], output shape must be a compile-time constant
     [[{{node model/tf_op_layer_strided_slice/strided_slice}}]]
    TPU compilation failed
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_626429452001451780/_8]]
```

when trying to train/fit the keras layered model, although from the above call-stack it's not clear at which point this error has occurred.

One more question would be, how do we clear the cache or buffer that is storing this error, so that we can reset the TPU and run our code again after making changes. And not have to restart sessions or kernels?

Answer (score 0):

When I run the same TPU initialization code in [Colab](http://colab.research.google.com) (runtime set to `TPU`):

```
tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
print(f"Running on TPU: {tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict()['worker']}")  
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
```

It runs without errors and reinitializes TPU and clears out eager cache, here are the logs:

```
Running on TPU: ['10.18.71.154:8470']
WARNING:tensorflow:TPU system grpc://10.18.71.154:8470 has already been initialized. Reinitializing the TPU can cause previously created variables on TPU to be lost.
WARNING:tensorflow:TPU system grpc://10.18.71.154:8470 has already been initialized. Reinitializing the TPU can cause previously created variables on TPU to be lost.
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.18.71.154:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.18.71.154:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Clearing out eager caches
INFO:tensorflow:Clearing out eager caches
....
```

For your second issue of "[4,?], output shape must be a compile-time constant", please give your model's input an output shapes when building your model.

Comment: I'm running the notebooks via Kaggle and not via Colab, the outputs vary. In my case, it didn't clear the cache each time. Let me try again and let's resolve the first one and then we can tackle the next problem.

Comment: Here's the links to all the (kernels) notebooks that are not working on the TPU - https://www.kaggle.com/c/tweet-sentiment-extraction/discussion/157158 (if you look at the older versions of the same kernel you can see the error messages mentioned above in the logs). You may need to log into Kaggle as a user to fork them and run them.